# How to access javascript object's properties dynamically based on textbox value?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mongodb, typescript

I am new to angular .I am stuck with generating or updating the table with respect to text box.
I have a schema which contains 3 fields-country,sales and profit.
There is two text box named as x and y axis.There is a table which should be generated on updating the x and y axis(text box).The should be of two columns in the table which tells what should be in x and y axis.

This is my **home.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
            <label>x-axis : </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName = "xaxis" >  <br>
            <label>y-axis : </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName ="yaxis" > <br>
            <button class="apply-btn" (click)='apply(myFormGroup.value)'>Apply</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{this.xaxis}}</th>
                <th>{{this.yaxis}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor = 'let product of products' cdkDrag>
                <td>{{product.xaxis}}</td>    **<----Here is the problem**
                <td>{{product.yaxis}}</td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my **home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{

    products:any=[];
    xaxis:any;
    yaxis:any;
    myFormGroup:FormGroup;

    constructor(private service : ServiceService,private fb : FormBuilder) { 
      this.CreateForm();
    }

    //Fetching of data
    refreshData(){
      this.service.getAll().subscribe((res) => {
      this.products=res;
      })  
    } 

    CreateForm(){
      this.myFormGroup=this.fb.group({
        xaxis:['',Validators.required],
        yaxis:['',Validators.required]
      });
    }

  apply(formValue){
    this.xaxis=formValue.xaxis;
    this.yaxis=formValue.yaxis;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.refreshData();
  }
}
```

The values should be in the text box is the attributes of schema i.e country,sales and profit.For example, when we enter country and sales for x and y axis respectively then the table should fetch the values of country and sales from the db and update the table with those values.

Comment: there's no `apply` function in your code used on the `click` event. and its a little unclear as what is that you want as output. consider adding a StackBlitz or a image or representation.

Comment: do you want to show product dynamically with the value of x and y axis? or what is your issue

Comment: I want to show the product dynamically using x and y axis - @BearNithi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **JavaScript Square Bracket** `[]` notation to access the product object properties dynamically. Square bracket notation accepts expressions, so you can pass the `this.xaxis` and `this.yaxis` in your product object. i.e, `product[this.xaxis]`

```
<div class="form-group">
        <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
            <label>x-axis : </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName = "xaxis" >  <br>
            <label>y-axis : </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName ="yaxis" > <br>
            <button class="apply-btn" (click)='apply(myFormGroup.value)'>Apply</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{this.xaxis}}</th>
                <th>{{this.yaxis}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor = 'let product of products' cdkDrag>
                <td>{{product[this.xaxis]}}</td>  
                <td>{{product[this.yaxis]}}</td>
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
```